# Cannot mount USB Flash Drive

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive

I cannot access the files in USB flash drive.

`lsusb` command lists the device:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1307:0163 Transcend Information, Inc. 256MB/512MB/1GB Flash Drive
...
```

However, it is not mounted automatically and I get the following error when I use `mount` command:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb /mnt/usb
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb
```

How can I fix this issue?

I get the following output when I run

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,LABEL
NAME   LABEL
sda
├─sda1 System Reserved
├─sda2
├─sda3
├─sda5
└─sda6
sr0
```

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Please run `sudo lsblk -o NAME,LABEL` or `sudo parted -l` from your terminal and post the output.

Comment: @ThatGuy I added the output to the post above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mount partitions, not the drive itself. Please try with the following commands (and let it find the file system automatically), for example

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

But this partition might be your root partition, which is already mounted. I think you want to mount a partition on the drive b, /dev/sdb. The problem is that the drive is not recognized as a mass storage device (not seen by lsblk).

You can try in another USB port of the same computer, in another computer and with another operating system (another linux distro or Windows or MacOS). If still no luck, I think your USB flash drive is damaged. See this link and links from it for more details.

[Pendrive lifetime](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297)

Comment: There is only `sdb` under `/dev` directory.

Comment: If there is only /dev/sdb and no partitions dev/sdb1 etc, the system does not see any partitions. Are there data in the drive, that you want to recover? Or can you create a new partition table with a partition with the FAT32 file system alias format the drive? Depending on the situation, there are different things to suggest.

Comment: I want to recover the data on the drive.

Comment: I suggest that you get another USB pendrive of at least the same size, clone your drive to that drive, and do the recovery work on that drive. It reduces the risk, to damage your drive. As long as it can be seen as /dev/sdb (or /dev/sdc ...) there is good hope, that mkusb can read it in a cloning process. Otherwise you can try with ddrescue. So install mkusb as described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb and try with the command line in the next comment.

Comment: sudo -H mkusb /dev/sdb

Comment: if the source drive for the cloning is /dev/sdb. mkusb will help you select the target drive in order to avoid overwriting any important data. I suggest that you try Testdisk and PhotoRec (on the cloned copy). See this link for more tips about repairing a drive or recovering data, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986

Comment: `sudo -H mkusb /dev/sdb` did not work either. It says `tmp/tmp.991BACAw34: line 1: /dev/sdb: No medium found
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0,000136963 s, 0,0 kB/s`

Comment: Are you sure that the USB pendrive is recognized as /dev/sdb? Please check again with lsblk, for example 'sudo lsblk -f' (without quotes).

Comment: I'm sure. I think the drive is dead.

Comment: That's bad, but it happens with USB pendrives. There might be a guarantee for a year or two, so if you are lucky you can get a new one without any cost.